# Open save dialog box doesn't close after user logouts from application in IE11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I have a download link in my application. If user clicks on the link, then a default open save dialog box is popped up in a new window in IE8. Also, user can't navigate anywhere till he clicks on open or save on this prompt.

But, the open save dialog is different and comes at bottom of the page in IE11 as given below. And also user can navigate anywhere in the application without responding to this save prompt. ***The problem is that this prompt is still there even after the user logouts from the application and can open or save even after logout***.

Is there any way to force the user to respond to open save dialog and then only navigate to other pages in IE11 or force dialog to close if user logs out  ?

IE8

[image]

IE11

[image]

Comment: Well putting internet explorer in the tags is one way of making sure nobody is going to look at your question.

Comment: @php_nub_qq: the issue is specific to IE11 and i have no other choice..

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately no, this is just the browser behavior and it cannot be altered, for good reason too. I would not want websites to have any control over download dialogue boxes that my browser presents to me.

If your goal is to prevent a user from downloading a file unless they are still logged in, you may serve the file via a script on your server, which first checks the login status before sending the file to the browser/user.